# How to set the timeout for Django development server (runserver)?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I have run the Django development server with

```
python.exe manage.py runserver
```

How can I set timeout (for example - 5 sec.) for runserver? I want to test the system behavior when timeout breaks the long requests.

Comment: You can not. As it was mentioned in `runserver` command docs, it is for development status and have a basic structure that lets you have a simple server. You can check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver) for details.

Meanwhile, why do not you use CTRL-C to stop server manually through the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can not.

As it was mentioned in `runserver` command [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver), it is for development status and have a basic structure that lets you have a simple server. You can check docs for details. It is not advised to use it as a production server so it is not meaningful to test *webserver-crash* situation on a server that **you must not use in production**.

Meanwhile, why do not you use CTRL-C to stop server manually through the command line?

Update: I understand your situation. But the thing is, you will make test with Django-Dev server and run your application on **another** server in production. It is odd to make tests on the one that will not be live server. You better setup the Web Server you will use in your production to your local environment and make test on that. Even though all offers similar functionalities, there could be things that will differ form software to software. So working on the web server product that you will use is the right way to go before making such tests.

Web servers can run any web software which is capable of. Check [Django-Apache documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for detalis but you can configure it to work with nginx or any other web server too.

Comment: I want to test the server behavior on developer's workplace. Ctrl-C is not quite what I want, because it's not a way to automate tests.

Comment: Is there a standard package of apache portable with Django wsgi, for local testing ?